# byte-wise operations on a xmm register (AMD64)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, cpu-registers

How can I access only a specific part (byte) of a `128bit xmm` register? I have to loop (bytewise) over the whole space, compare byte after byte and copy it on well defined conditions*.

Therefore I have to compare every byte of this 16-byte register with `\0` and (maybe) overwrite it.

```
xor %ecx, %ecx #var i

copy:
    cmp $0, <i-th byte of xmm1>
    je end
    mov <byte i of xmm1>, <byte i of xmm2>
    inc %ecx
    jmp copy
end:
# ...
```

How to access the i-th byte of xmm registers?

My solution has to use as less operations as possible (only the number of ops count, not the number of their clock cycles!), so I will not use sub-functions like strlen etc.

*) I have to move all bytes, unit the the first `\0` occurrence within b, from register a to register b.

Comment: http://www.strchr.com/sse2_optimised_strlen?allcomments=1

Comment: if you want memcmp then look at these pages http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/x86_64/string/memcmp.s and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796562/why-is-this-slower-than-memcmp

Comment: or if you want memcpy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260602/how-to-increase-performance-of-memcpy

Comment: Starting with SSE4.2, the instruction `PCMPISTRI` can be used to find the first null character of a byte string. [Proof-of-concept](http://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can access bytes using `PEXTRB` but that's not recommended for this task. I would do a SIMD compare using `PCMPEQB` then `PMOVMSKB` to get the result mask, then look up the first set bit using `BSF` then create a blend mask from that. Avoid looping, use parallelism.

---

**Update**: based on [rwong's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283118/byte-wise-operations-on-a-xmm-register-amd64/22283246?noredirect=1#comment33864094_22283118) here is a possible implementation using `pcmpistrm`:

```
3       movdqu input, %xmm1
(gdb) si
4       movdqu replace, %xmm2
(gdb)
5       movdqa %xmm1, %xmm0
(gdb)
6       pcmpistrm $0x78, %xmm1, %xmm1
(gdb) p/s $xmm1.v16_int8
$1 = "input\000----------"
(gdb) p/s $xmm2.v16_int8
$2 = "replacereplacere"
(gdb) si
7       pblendvb %xmm1, %xmm2
(gdb) si
8       ret
(gdb) p/s $xmm2.v16_int8
$3 = "repla\000----------"
```

Comment: Is there a proper way to set all bits until index i to 1. Or do I have to left-shift `resultOfBSF`-times and add always 1?

Comment: My guess would be to use a lookup table.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I was able to create a quite good solution. I have only a problem with values greater than 128 byte, so I will have to drop the solution and do it with a loop :/